# can not dropdown when summernote on the boostrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I use summernote on the bootstrap modal.But when click the dropdown item on the toolbar, the dropdown menu not show on the right place or even not exit the drop down DOM.I'll show you the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro6Ad.png)

And I've search for a long time in summernote github issue list and stackoverflow.I try add "dialogsInBody: true", but not working.Anyone can help me about this problem.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

Comment: Can you please expand a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Here work fine.

```
callbacks: {
        onInit: function() {
            //when inside a modal, re-link the dropdown
            var thisNote = $(this);

            if(thisNote.closest('.modal').length>0){
                thisNote.next().find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
            }

        }
    }
```